# Get the Next Date of the following Sunday (Not using Calendar)

Tags: java, gwt

I need a solution to get the next Sunday's date, please no "Calendar" I am using GWT and it does not compile.. too many errors. I need an alternate solution... I am kind of new to java and have spent two days "just" trying to programatically get the next Sundays date.. Please help me (No Calendar Class please)

Regards

Comment: AFAIK, You have three options: 1) write your own implementation to calculate next Sunday, 2) use [JSNI](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&s=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&t=DevGuideJavaScriptNativeInterface) and write the your calculation in pure Javascript, or 3) [perform the calculation server-side](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/gwtDateTime#Server_Side_-_-_Start_and_End_Of_Day) using the Calendar class.

Answer (score 1):

You want a perpetual calendar algorithm.  Several are outlined here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_the_day_of_the_week

Comment: I guess this is too advanced for a beginner like me.. thanks though

Comment: Are you new to Java or to programming in general?  In any event, write out the algorithm in language you understand (C, Fortran, English, French, whatever), then translate it to Java -- don't attempt to code directly into Java if you're not comfortable with the language.